# Who should create the ViewModel in iOS MVVM?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm

I am trying to develop a simple app to understand `MVVM` but I don't get it really well. I've read some articles, but they are a bit different:

[View in different class MVVM](http://jpellat.com/how-to-separate-view-controllers-from-his-view-logic/)

In this example the view  is not the `ViewController` itself, it is a class that contains all the details of the `view` and it is an abstraction for the `VC`.
The `ViewController` creates the `ViewModel` with some data the it retrieve from DB, Network..
The `ViewController` talks with the `model` and manage the `ViewModel` to update the `view`.

[ViewController is the view MVVM](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/model-view-viewmodel-for-ios/)

In this example, the `viewController` is the view, it does not need other class. The `viewModel` is not created by the viewController, and the `ViewModel` of the next `ViewController` is created by a `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` also has an instances of the `Model`, so if it needs to retrieve some data, it has instances of the DB, Network..
I don't understand well some things. If the `viewModel` is retrieving data from Network with asynchronous tasks and I want to display an spinner and get data for fulfil the view. Should I user `blocks`, `KVO` or `delegates`? If I use `delegates`, the `view` implements `ViewModelDelegate` Methods, would be that correct? Am I coupling `view` with `viewModel`? I am confused at this point.

If I have a `firstViewModel` that creates a new `secondViewModel` for a new pushed `SecondViewController`,and `FirstViewController` has to update its view before the user pops the pushed `SecondViewController`. In this case `firstViewModel` has to observe `secondViewModel` and notify the changes to `firstViewController` once popped, doesn't it?

I also have a question about `ViewController` creation. `ViewControllers` are the attendants of next ViewControllers creation? If I create an object that manages `ViewControllers` creation and navigation should I pass this object over `viewModels`?

I know they are very similar, but I am confused about which way I should implement and how. There isn't much information and examples about `iOS` `MVVM`.

I am not using `Reactive Cocoa` yet because I want to understand this pattern well first. Though it is in my TO-DO list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on why you're using MVVM. I'm doing it right in the middle of the two cases you mention, actually. Here's the two reasons for MVVM usage:

First, you may be using MVVM because you want to organize your code in a way that pulls the logic out of the VC and keeps it clean. In this case, you're using a ViewModel in good OOP form and it's perfectly find to have the VC create it.

On the other hand, you may be intending on UI testing your VC's and therefore want to introduce mock ViewModels. In this case, you want to be handing the ViewModel to the VC. (i.e. dependency injection)

In my view, either is justifiable. You might even have multiple needs in one app. Therefore, I keep things flexible. My approach is to create the VM in the viewDidLoad() method of the VC **only if** it doesn't exist yet. This allows me to use my normal VM and to do create it (neatly) in my VC, but if I ever need to override it (unit testing, UI testing, alternate view style), I can, too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact Cocoa apps, are by definition using MVC, and you have to try and make MVVM work with the underlying ViewController structure.

I haven't looked at MVVM in iOS, but have done a bit using Xamarin.Forms, where the View is just the XAML code, the view model interacts with the View and the Model. Under Cocoa apps, it doesn't really matter too much how you do the ViewModel part, but looking at your links, I think the second approach is closer to a purer MVVM approach.

I suggest you download the code in the link and have a look to get a greater understanding?